# Multiple collection view on one view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, ios10

I have 4 `collection view` on one `view controller` and different data has to be fetched from api for every view controller.

The data has been fetched one by one but how to fetch data for all `collection view` at the same time.

As i know i can use `CollectionView DataSource` and delegate methods for once and i have to implement methods for 4  collection view in one but it app crashes giving error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HomeScreenViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem??

Comment: Did you implement the [UICollectionViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource) delegate?

Comment: You need somehow to recognize collection objects, and depending on which collection view is to load with data you need to. I suggest using tags on objects of collection.

Comment: yes i have implement data source delegate @d.felber

Comment: @AjayDang can you add the implementation to your question?

Comment: Create a subclass of CollectionView. Add a property or enum to recognize each CollectionView. Add condition in data source and delegate methods and manipulate data accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you use a separate `UICollectionViewController` for each of your collection views. This can be achieved easily in the InterfaceBuilder via `ContainerViews`.

Coordinating all four CollectionViews in one View Controller is possible - but ugly.

[image: ViewController embedding multiple CollectionViewControllers via ContainerViews]